# Multinomial logit with random effects does not converge using mblogit

Tags: r, multinomial, convergence, random-effects, logits

I would like to estimate a random effects (RE) multinomial logit model.

I have been applying mblogit from the [mclogit package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclogit/mclogit.pdf). However, once I introduce RE into my model, it fails to converge.
Is there a workaround this?

For instance, I tried to adjust the fitting process of mblogit and increase the maximal number of iterations (maxit), but did not succeed to correctly write the syntax for the control function. Would this be the right approach? And if so, could you advise me how to implement it into my model which so far looks as follows:

```
meta.mblogit <- mblogit(Migration  ~ ClimateHazard4 , weights = logNsquare,
data = meta.df,   subset= Panel==1,  random = ~1|StudyID,
)
```

Here, both variables (Migration and ClimateHazard4) are factor variables.

Or is there an alternative approach you could recommend me for an estimation of RE multinomial logit?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello! This is a question that I believe has been explored on stats.stackexchange.com a few times. I'd suggest taking a look at questions/answers on that site, eg https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242109/model-failed-to-converge-warning-in-lmer. Increasing the max iterations is a good idea! Can you post the code used that did not work? Some other ideas: Have you tried alternative optimizers? Will the model fit if you exclude the random intercept? Do you have enough data to fit a model of this complexity? Have you considered including the RI as a fixed effect?

Comment: I tried to increase the number of iterations  as follows:
meta.mblogit <- mblogit(...
                        control=if (length(random)) 
                                mmclogit.control(epsilon = 1e-08,
                                                 maxit = 50, trace=TRUE,) 
                        else 
                                mclogit.controlmclogit.control(epsilon = 1e-08,
                                                        maxit = 50, trace=TRUE)
                                )
But this did not work.

Comment: @Skaqqs Also, the model indeed fits  when I exclude the RE. I am not entirely sure how to change the optimizer in mblogit explicitly. So if you have any suggestions as for any of the issues, i.e. how to change the control function and optimizer, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `mblogit(Migration  ~ ClimateHazard4 , weights = logNsquare,
data = meta.df,   subset= Panel==1,  random = ~1|StudyID, control = mclogit.control(maxit = 1000))` to increase the max iterations to 1000.

Comment: @Skaqqs I also tried this, but receive the following: "Error in if (control$trace.inner) cat("\n") : argument is of length zero" I think the syntax is wrong, but I am not sure what the right one would be. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Does it work if you use `..., mmclogit.control(maxit=1000))` Try it with the example data: `data(electors); mclogit(cbind(Freq,interaction(time,class)) ~ econ.left/class+ welfare/class + auth/class, random = ~1|party, data = electors, control = mmclogit.control(maxit = 1000))`

Comment: @Skaqqs this worked perfectly, meaning that the model managed to run but it still failed to converge. Do you have any other idea what I could try? That would be much appreciated.

Comment: That suggests to me that now your iterations parameter now has the correct syntax; however, the function could not fit the model to your data. Some ideas: simpler model, more data, simpler random effect structure, specify your random effect as a fixed effect, use a different package/function (eg `nnet::multinom`)... just off the top of my head. Clearly some ideas may not be suitable based on your situation. If you send me your study design and data, I could provide more precise feedback. Otherwise, I highly suggest reading questions/answers on the site like I linked in a previous comment.